# SharePoint API - Retrieve site contents

Tags: api, sharepoint

I'm trying to call a SharePoint API to get the all the items from Site contents. I have tried using requests such as https://ipagovtest.sharepoint.com/sites/IPTesting/_api/web/lists to get a list but doesn't seem to be working. I have a screenshot below of the items I'm trying to get via the uRL. Any assistance on how I can convert the URL to an api call would be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific regarding "not working" (i.e. why do you think the "/_api/web/lists" does not work)?

Answer (score 1):

You original question was not specific in terms of which API you're calling or how you're authenticating to it.  Let's consider Microsoft's recommended approach which is using OAuth2/MSAL and the Graph API to get all lists of a given site.  You would begin by retrieving a list of all the lists on a given site like this:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var lists = await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"].Lists.Request().GetAsync();
```

You can then iterate through each list the usual way like this:

```
foreach (var list in lists)
{
    //Do something with list
}
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

[More information about working with SharePoint lists using Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/list?view=graph-rest-1.0)